# Parler de quelqu'un dont le nom contient une particule ?

Tags: grammaire, noms-de-famille

Une fois de plus, une question me taraude : comment doit-on parler de quelqu'un dont le nom contient une particule ? Y a-t-il une règle autre que « ça sonne bien » ? Le nombre de syllabes ne semble pas suffire, voir plus bas (je ne mentionne pas la noblesse pour ne pas susciter de débat sur l'ascendance de De Gaulle ou celle de Villepin et considère ici qu'on écrit « de Gaulle » sans majuscule).

Par exemple :

> Je lis le livre de Sade mais celui de De (de ?) Gaulle, et je déjeune
>   avec Villepin avant de prendre un thé avec Castries (de Castries ?).

---

Quelques secondes de recherches supplémentaires m'ont fait découvrir cette [page Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particule_%28onomastique%29). Il semblerait que l'on conserve la particule pour les noms d'une syllabe (ici, de Castries, prononcé de Castres), sauf pour Sade, Maistre, Retz et Broglie (prononcé Breuil). Wikipédia n'indique cependant pas de source précise (Maistre, ou de Maistre, aurait demandé à ce que l'on dise « Maistre », mais je ne sais pas quel est l'usage, ma question reste ouverte).

Comment: C'est plus compliqué que ce qu'il y parait en effet... Il ne semble y avoir que des *exceptions qui confirment la règle*... Je supprime donc ma réponse qui ne semble pas pertinente... @cl-r Je vous laisse rajouter votre commentaire qui était attaché à ma réponse...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grevisse, *Le Bon Usage*, indique (§1052, c) :

> [Le *de* nobiliaire] se maintient pour unir le nom au prénom, au titre de noblesse ou aux titres de *monsieur*, *madame*, *monseigneur*, etc. — au mot *famille*, aux noms de parenté (*frère*, *oncle*, etc.)
>
> Il disparaît normalement en dehors de ces conditions. Cependant, selon Littré, « on laisse le *de*, même sans prénom, qualification ou titre : 1) devant les noms d'une syllabe ou de deux avec un *e* muet ; 2) devant les noms qui commencent par une voyelle ou un *h* muet. »

Et ça continue avec des cas particuliers (*duc en Bavière* p.e.) et des exemples où des bons auteurs n'ont pas respecté la règle.

Answer (score 6):

Quelques citations de l'article [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particule_%28onomastique%29) :

> #### La particule nobiliaire : une piste trompeuse
>
> Contrairement à une idée reçue, la particule ne peut en aucun cas être prise comme une marque de noblesse (pas plus d'ailleurs que son absence empêche d'être noble)
>
> ## Règles d’usage

### De

> Elle n’apparaît que lorsque le nom est **précédé d’un prénom, d’un titre ou d'une dénomination** (monsieur, madame, marquis, abbé, général, etc.) :
>
> > *Madame de Sévigné*
>
> Subtilité « historique » : de façon systématique jusqu'au Grand Siècle, et parfois encore de nos jours, on trouve la particule employée après un lien de parenté (comme cousin(e), oncle/tante, grand-père/grand-mère).
>
> On peut ainsi trouver :
>
> > *ma cousine de Maintenon, ma grand-mère de Bourbon-Parme*
>
> Lorsque le nom est employé **sans prénom ou sans titre**, le « de » n’est pas maintenu :
>
> > *La Fontaine*
>
> De même, **au pluriel**, le « de » disparaît :
>
> > *Les Montherlant* et non *les de Montherlant*
>
> Toutefois, on conserve ordinairement la particule « de » pour les **noms d'une syllabe sonore** (le *e* final étant muet) :
>
> > *de Thou
> >
> > de Sèze*
>
> **Exception** : l'usage veut qu'on omette le « de » pour Sade, Maistre, Retz, Broglie (prononcé Breuil sauf à Strasbourg où l'on prononce communément Broglie pour la place Broglie).

### D', Du et Des

> Mais « d’ », « Du » ou « Des » sont maintenus :
>
> > *Du Guesclin
> >
> > Des Cars
> >
> > d’Alembert*

### De et D'

> La particule « de » / « d' » n’est généralement pas prise en compte dans le classement alphabétique : de Sèze sera classé sous *S* plutôt que sous D, de même que d'Alembert sera classé sous A plutôt que sous *D*.
>
> #### Majuscule ou minuscule ?
>
> « de » et « d’ » : la particule étant une préposition marquant l'origine, elle s'écrit **toujours en minuscule** :
>
> > *Raymond de Sèze*
>
> Si elle est **précédée de la préposition « de »**, la majuscule permet de distinguer les deux « de »:
>
> > *les mémoires de Raymond de Sèze*
> > *les mémoires de De Sèze*

### Du et Des

> « du » et « des », prennent une capitale quand ils ne sont **pas précédés d'un prénom ou d'un titre** :
>
> > *un roman de Guy des Cars
> >
> > le romancier des Cars
> >
> > un livre de Des Cars
> >
> > les ruses de Bertrand du Guesclin
> >
> > le rusé Du Guesclin*
>
> Dans un index, ces noms à particule du ou des sont classés à *du* ou à *des* : on place Du Bellay à la lettre *d*, non à *b*.)

### Noms à article séparé (màj 2022)

> Pour les noms propres qui comportent un article initial séparé du nom par une espace, tels « La » pour « La Fontaine », contrairement à l’usage du xviie siècle, la majuscule est en France de règle à l'initiale de l'article
>
> Cavelier de La Salle ;
> Jean de La Bruyère ;
> le chevalier de La Barre ;
> le marquis de La Fayette.
>
> Dans les classements alphabétiques modernes, ces noms sont rangés à « La », « Le », « Les ».
>
> > [ Wikipédia - « [*Particule (onomastique)*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particule_%28onomastique%29) » ]

Answer (score 3):

En complément, au sujet de la *majuscule*; pour paraphraser *Le Bon Usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Boeck-Duculot) au §101 c) :

1. « *De* » **préposition** pour indiquer l'origine n'est pas considéré comme partie du nom: prend la **minuscule**. La distinction noble/non-noble
   joue peu ici puisque les exemples de majuscules sont surtout
   présents quand il y a agglutination de la particule avec le
   nom;

   - les particules étrangères équivalentes (comme *von*, *van*) : surtout en minuscule en France, majuscule l'emportant pour *van* en Belgique
   - en néerlandais, le « *de* » n'est pas préposition mais article, devrait recevoir la majuscule : souvent confondu avec la préposition en France, donc on retrouve aussi la minuscule
   - l'article néerlandais « *de* » et ses variantes ne prennent pas la majuscule après "van".
2. Si le nom contient un article qui suit la préposition « *de* », l'**article** aura souvent la **majuscule** mais il y a hésitation;

   - Si le nom est employé sans « *de* », l'article prend presque toujours la majuscule, mais l'usage peut varier.
3. Avec l'**article contracté** (*du, des*), le critère de nobilité est davantage applicable, et plus forte la nobilité, plus on utilise la *minuscule*; quoique souvent la *majuscule* avec des personnages du passé, mais la minuscule si le sens géographique l'emporte.<sup>1</sup>

---

*De Gaulle*. On note incidemment que selon la règle présentée dans la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13993), la particule est requise. Par ailleurs, les règles générales visant la majuscule (*LBU* §98) s'appliquent nonobstant. *LBU* n'approuve pas, par exemple, « *von Wartburg* » en début de phrase. On y souligne aussi la *curiosité* dans l'utilisation de la préposition « *de* » en majuscule avec « *de Gaulle* » pour différencier deux prépositions identiques (*de De Gaulle*). Dans le même ordre d'idées, on  remarque un passage d'intérêt à la *BDL* ([voir aussi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3497)) :

> Toutefois, on met la majuscule si le patronyme est directement précédé
>   d’une préposition. Notons cependant qu’il est préférable d’éviter de
>   placer côte à côte la préposition *de* et la particule nobiliaire, si
>   celle-ci n’est ni élidée ni contractée. On préférera donc *J’ai lu une
>   biographie du général de Gaulle* à *J’ai lu une biographie de De Gaulle*.
>
> [ *La Banque de dépannage linguistique* (BDL),«  [Noms de
>   personnes](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1345) » ]

---

<sub>1. Un mot sur les [toponymes](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/normes-procedures/regles-ecriture/minuscule-majuscule.html) (au Québec), qui font l'objet de règles particulières, et où la particule prend la majuscule (par exemple, [*Rue De Gaulle*](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/ToposWeb/recherche.aspx?s=De%20Gaulle&x=0&y=0)).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

La règle simple est que la particule doit être élidée, sauf quand elle est précédée par un substantif:  les Rohan-chabot, mais le duc de Rohan,  ma cousine de Ménars, mais les Ménars, etc, etc....